# Flask does not see React's 'bundle.js', only 'index.html'

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, webpack

I am trying to run a Flask app (`app.py`) and load `index.html` that uses a dynamically generated React `bundle.js`, but seems the latter cannot be found for some reason. This is the error that I am getting in the browser console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/bundle.js 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Here is the project tree structure I am using:

```
.
|-- __init__.py
|-- static
|   |-- dist
|   |   `-- bundle.js
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- node_modules
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- package-lock.json
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- App.css
|   |   |-- App.js
|   |   |-- components
|   |   |   |-- SearchBar.js
|   |   |   `-- Table.js
|   |   |-- index.css
|   |   `-- index.js
|   `-- webpack.config.js
`-- app.py
```

Contents of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>WebTitan</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And lastly `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static/dist', template_folder='static')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I am using the following command to generate `bundle.js`:

`webpack --watch --mode development --config webpack.config.js`

Is there something I am missing?